# On hover, DIV expands and overlaps others

Tags: jquery, html, hover, jquery-animate

I am looking to do something very simple. I have many DIV boxes arranged in a grid. When I hover one of them, I want it to expand slowly, anchored from the middle, and then shrink back down. However, I have not been able to do so without the other DIV boxes being pushed aside. I want the DIV being hovered on to expand slowly, overlapping the other DIV boxes, without moving them.
I have accomplished some of this with JQuery.
Here is what I have:

CSS:

```
div{width: 100px; height: 100px; float: left;}
div#sq1{background-color: magenta;}
div#sq2{background-color: yellow;}
div#sq3{background-color: cyan;}
```

JQuery:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='animated.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").hover(function(){
        if (!$(this).hasClass('animated')) {
            $(this).dequeue().stop().animate({ width: "100px", height: "100px" });
    }
    }, function() {
        $(this).addClass('animated').animate({ width: "200px", height: "200px" }, "normal", "linear", function() {
        $(this).removeClass('animated').dequeue();
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="dequeue" class="blocks">
<div id="sq1"></div>
<div id="sq2"></div>
<div id="sq3"></div>
</div>
```

Here's how I want it to look: 
Before : http://i39.tinypic.com/dh9x87.png
After: http://i44.tinypic.com/70cd35.png

Thanks!

Comment: I see nine boxes in the image and three boxes in the markup that you posted. this confuses me :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using **negative margins** to trick the page into thinking each box is still 100px x 100px.  So in addition to animating the width and height from 100px to 200px, **also animate the margin** from 0 to -50px.

Hope this helps :)

**EDIT**

Here's a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/sGDvj/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are trying to do :D although I do not have a 100% positive answer, I do have a suggestion, try playing around with the z-index of the divs, maybe make the one you are hovering over to somthing like 5 or whatever positive number you want!

Answer (score 0):

why not use absolute positions? or another way to do it is to create a duplicate div over the one that is hovered over and animate it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just use CSS3 simple and easy

http://jsfiddle.net/mhkfH/

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/4uvfZ/

(Note the change to the first selector)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/tdsNF/2/
and see [Expand / shrink div on hover / out with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056950/expand-shrink-div-on-hover-out-with-jquery) for the credits.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example; I think this is what you want to do.
http://jsfiddle.net/tdsNF/2/

It is an expander with images, but divs will work as well, I believe.

Found it here: [Expand / shrink div on hover / out with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056950/expand-shrink-div-on-hover-out-with-jquery)

```
var $imageWidth     = 92,    // with borders
$imageColumns    = 10;    // images across

$("#container > div .img").each(function(index) {
var $left = (index % $imageColumns * $imageWidth);
$(this).css("left", $left + "px");
});

$(".img a img").hover(function() {
    $(this).closest(".img").css("z-index", 1);
    $(this).stop(true,true).animate({ height: "200", width: "200", left: "-=55", top: "-=55" }, "fast");
    $("#name").css("color", "#242424").html($(this).attr("data-name"));
    $("#school").css("color", "#242424").html($(this).attr("data-school"));
}, function() {
$(this).closest(".img").css("z-index", 0);
$(this).stop(true,true).animate({ height: "90", width: "90", left: "+=55", top: "+=55"     }, "fast");
});​
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I suppose my SO etiquette is still a little unrefined. Thanks for the tip, good to know.