# Expand / shrink div on hover / out with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, hover, position

I am looking for a `jQuery` plugin to expand `div` elements so as to reveal their overflow (if any) on hover. Illustration:

[image]

The plugin should work on relatively positioned `div`'s (which I guess implies that you create a copy of the `div`, set its positioning to absolute, then figure out where to place it).

**Is there such a plugin already available out there?**

Comment: What's the content? Images and/or text/more divs with unpredictable rendering? Is there a fixed aspect ratio? There's not enough information...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You don't need a plugin.
Just add proper css and use jQuery animate:

```
$div
.on('mouseenter', function(){
    $(this).animate({ margin: -10, width: "+=20", height: "+=20" });
})
.on('mouseleave', function(){
    $(this).animate({ margin: 0, width: "-=20", height: "-=20" });
})​
```

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/evJey/212)

Comment: This should be the prefered answer IMHO, for such a lean code.

Comment: @tborychowski awesome elegant timeless code! +1 upvote for this solution and i agree with the two comments (also upvoted those). Now I am trying to convert your solution from table to table-less (and even simpler, cleaner) html element version but I am stuck: http://jsfiddle.net/c15bpk30/  Can you please have a look and see what I have overlooked in this conversion? Thanks!

Comment: here is: http://jsfiddle.net/c15bpk30/1/ because you used custom html tags, they are not `display: block` by default. So you just need to set that on your `project` tag and it should work. Moreover, this should not need any js now, just pure css transitions :-)

Answer (score 25):

The images are missing here... but here is how I pulled this off a few years ago. The basic theory is that all of the images/div's whatever are absolute, inside of their own relative area.  I then animate the `left & top` position both `-negatively`. This makes them protrude above the surrounding boxes and look like they are popping out. (Of course you also need to make sure the z-index of this one is higher than the ones around it).

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tdsNF/1/)

```
$(".img a img").hover(function() {
    $(this).closest(".img").css("z-index", 1);

    // this is where the popping out effect happens
    $(this).animate({ height: "200", width: "200", left: "-=55", top: "-=55" }, "fast");

}, function() {
    $(this).closest(".img").css("z-index", 0);
    $(this).animate({ height: "90", width: "90", left: "+=55", top: "+=55" }, "fast");
});​
```

The styles I have for these two things are:

```
.img { 
   position:relative; 
   z-index:0px;  
}

.img a img { 
   position:absolute;
   border:1px #1b346c solid; 
   background:#f1f1f1; 
   width:90px; 
   height:90px; 
}
```

Comment: Very nice `mcpDESIGNS`. I have just added `.stop(true,true)` before animate as it cancels the animation of previous elements and improves the visual effect in my opinion: http://jsfiddle.net/tdsNF/2/

Comment: Ah yeah there's definitely some small improvements that could be made, did this about 2 years ago! Took me a while to figure out at the time, hope my sweat and tears were worth it :P haha

Comment: ... why are you effectively re-inventing the jQuery UI effect "scale"?

Comment: @specializt Scale wouldn't work in the manner needed for this demo to be done.

Comment: @MarkPieszak great answer! but is there any possibilty to make it by .on()? for dynamically created elements. thanks

Comment: Yes of course @the_ousek just do the dynamic on object syntax. `$(document).on({ 'mouseover': function () { }, 'mouseout': function () { } }, '.your-selector');` voila =) those 2 functions being basically what hover and the other is. This code is very old

Comment: @MarkPieszak thanks for answer, man! I did the same, as you wrote. but there was still a problem with first handler. the animation was launching again and again. found solution. use mouseenter instead of mouseover. may I post new answer with thanks to you?

Comment: Sure go for it and ahh yes thats the right one. I'm on a phone 

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @MarkPieszak. For **dynamically created** elements use

```
$(document).on({
  mouseenter: function () {
    $(this).animate({ height: "200", width: "200", left: "-=55", top: "-=55" }, "fast");
  },
  mouseleave: function () {
    $(this).animate({ height: "90", width: "90", left: "+=55", top: "+=55" }, "fast");
  }    
}, '.img a img');
```

`.hover()` does work only on static elements. more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180546/jquery-hover-not-working-with-dynamic-elements)

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this entirely with css, this is a snipet from a website of mine, im entirly too lazy to edit it, but you get the idea:

```
<ul class="hover">
  <li style="margin-top:40px;"">
   <a href=""><img src="images/Home/Home.jpg" alt="home" style="width:130px; height:100px;"/>
   <img src="images/Home/Home.jpg" alt="home" class="preview" style="width:180px; height:150px;"/></a>
  </li>
  <li style="margin-left:55px; margin-top:-20px;">
   <a href=""><img src="images/About/About.jpg" alt="About The Author" style="width:200px; height:200px;"/>
   <img src="images/About/About.jpg" alt="About The Author" class="preview" style="width:250px; height:250px;"/></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
/* begin hover */

.hover{
cursor: default;
list-style: none;
}

.hover a .preview{
display: none;
}

.hover a:hover .preview{
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: -33px;
left: -45px;
z-index: 1;
}

.hover img{
background: white;
border-color: black;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 4px;
color: inherit;
padding: 2px;
vertical-align: top;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
}

.hover li{
background: black;
border-color: black;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
color: inherit;
display: block;
float: left;
margin: 3px;
padding: 5px;
position: relative;
}

.hover .preview{
border-color:black;
border-width:8px;
border-stle:solid;
}

li{
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
}
```

there are some not needed styles in there but again, you get the idea. basically youre just showing one image on top of the original, on hover

Answer (score 0):

If it is text, it is a little more complicated...

I use it like this:

```
$('.floating').mouseenter(function(){
  const $this = $(this);
  const dimension = $this.data('dimension');
  const ratioEnlarged = 2;

  const tempElement = $this.clone();
  tempElement.appendTo('body');
  tempElement.css({
    width: dimension.width,
    height: dimension.height
  });

  if(tempElement.is(':offscreen')){
    // Change this to animate if you want it animated.
    $this.css({
      'margin-left': -dimension.width * ratioEnlarged/2,
      'margin-top': -dimension.height * ratioEnlarged/4,
      'font-size': ratioEnlarged + 'em',
      width: dimension.width * ratioEnlarged,
      height: dimension.height * ratioEnlarged
    });
  } else {
    $this.css({
      'margin-left': -dimension.width * ratioEnlarged/4,
      'margin-top': -dimension.height * ratioEnlarged/4,
      'font-size': ratioEnlarged + 'em',
      width: dimension.width * ratioEnlarged,
      height: dimension.height * ratioEnlarged
    });
  }

  tempElement.remove();
});

$('.floating').mouseleave(function(event) {
  const $this = $(this);
  const dimension = $this.data('dimension');

  if(!$this.hasClass('context-menu-active')){
    $this.css({
      margin: 0,
      'font-size': '1em',
      width: dimension.width,
      height: dimension.height
    });
  }
});
```