# jQuery hover not working with dynamic elements

Tags: php, jquery, hover

Im getting data out of a database, and based on the number of matches, I want to output this:

```
 <div id='link_delete_holder' style='position:absolute;left:590px;top:10px'>
            <img id='link_delete' src='images/account_related/icons/link_delete.png'/>
        </div>
```

I want that image to be changing on hover, so I use this code:

```
$('#link_delete').hover(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', 'images/account_related/icons/link_delete_h.png');
}, function(){
    $(this).attr('src', 'images/account_related/icons/link_delete.png');
    });
```

Now, the problem is it only works on the first record (the first link_delete image that gets displayed), and seems like it doesn't apply to other images.

Comment: try to change `id="link_delete"` to `class="link_delete"` and then change `$('#link_delete')` to `$('.link_delete')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to have dynamic data created, don't use an ID to grab them because it is not valid HTML to have two elements with the same ID. Use a class with the same name and it will work fine.

```
<div id='link_delete_holder' style='position:absolute;left:590px;top:10px'>
    <img class='link_delete' src='images/account_related/icons/link_delete.png'/>
</div>
```

Also, as Anoop Joshi points out you cannot use a direct `$('#link_delete').hover(...);` you need to use a delegate and using what I said from above add the delegate based on the class not the ID, and you should use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` as that is essentially what `.hover(func(), func())` is doing.

```
$('.link_delete').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).attr('src', 'images/account_related/icons/link_delete_h.png');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).attr('src', 'images/account_related/icons/link_delete.png');
    }    
});
```

EDIT:

Added a working [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qgTzE/4/) that has dynamically created images that will `on hover` change the image and then back when you're done hovering.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [delegates](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for dynamically created objects.

```
$(document).on("hover","#link_delete",function(){
  $(this).attr('src', 'images/account_related/icons/link_delete_h.png');
});
```

Comment: I don't think this is the real problem. the issue is he uses id instead of class so that jQuery selector matches first element only, also, he dont mentioned any dynamic elements in client side.

Comment: @JasonOOO image has the id link_delete

Comment: but you knew that ID should match one element and should be unique its not like a class see prove! http://jsfiddle.net/4hE86/5/

Comment: @JasonOOO he want the hovering effect only on that image. Then whats the problem?

Comment: `is it only works on the first record (the first link_delete image that gets displayed), and seems like it doesn't apply to other images`

Comment: @JasonOOO OP didnt mension about multiple images