# Jquery: on() not firing for dynamic element

Tags: jquery, dynamic

I've seen a few different solutions but I can't seem to make them work. The solution I attempted is based on this question:[jQuery hover not working with dynamic elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180546/jquery-hover-not-working-with-dynamic-elements). I'm not seeing a distinguishable difference between the answer provided for that question and my own.

Here's the link for the jsfiddle that they used also: http://jsfiddle.net/qgTzE/4/

Dynamically created element:

```
<div class="deckCardListCard floatRight ui-corner-all" data-cardID="190563" id="1">190563</div>
```

Javascript to add hover:

```
        $(".deckCardListCard").on({
            mouseenter: function() {
                $("#deckCardDisplay").css("background-image", "url('images/cards/" + $(this).attr("data-cardID") + ".png')");
            },
            mouseleave: function() {
                $("#deckCardDisplay").css("background-image", "url('images/layout/back.png')");
            }
        });
```

** EDIT **

I have selected an answer from below but the question is more why what I have doesn't work when the apparent same thing works here: [jQuery hover not working with dynamic elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180546/jquery-hover-not-working-with-dynamic-elements)

Comment: you're targeting ` $("#deckCardDisplay")` but the `id` in dynamically generated div that you mention is "1" are you sure you're not missing something here.

Comment: yes, #deckCardDisplay is a static div that shows the image of the card when hovering over the dynamically created .deckCardListCard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this for event delegation from existing parent element or document or body: you read about it [here](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/#event-propagation)

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".deckCardListCard", function(){
     $("#deckCardDisplay").css("background-image", "url('images/cards/" + $(this).attr("data-cardID") + ".png')");
}).on("mouseleave", ".deckCardListCard", function(){
     $("#deckCardDisplay").css("background-image", "url('images/layout/back.png')");
});
```

Comment: I still don't understand why what I have doesn't work. I've seen the solution you provided in other places but the solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180546/jquery-hover-not-working-with-dynamic-elements Seems to be exactly what I've done. Either way, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a parent element/container, you should target that:

assume this:

```
<div id="parent"> ... your dynamic elements here ... </div>
```

Then use something like

```
$('#parent').on('.deckCardListCard', 'mouseenter', function(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to delegate these events is to pass `selector` param and bind event to static parent container:

```
$('#link_delete_holder').on({
     mouseenter: function () {
         $(this).attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/250x150');
     },
     mouseleave: function () {
         $(this).attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/150x150');
     }
 }, '.link_delete');
```

### -DEMO-